# Python / Tkinter : Random number in function

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to get a random number (in "boucle") all the time i press the button, but when i do it, it gives me the same number

```
def boucledef(boucle=random.randint(0,10)):
    global copienom, listprob
    if boucle>0:
        nom=selectRandom(listprob)
        while copienom == nom:
            nom=selectRandom(listprob)
        copienom=nom
        global myLabel
            
        if boucle >1:
            delete_label()
            myLabel = Label(root, text=nom, font=("Arial",20), bg = couleur_bg, fg = "#2C2E75")
            myLabel.pack(pady=10)
        
        if boucle ==1:
            delete_label()
            myLabel = Label(root, text=nom+" is choosen", font=("Arial",20), bg = couleur_bg, fg = "#2C2E75")
            myLabel.pack(pady=10)
            DeleteButton["state"]=NORMAL
            file_menu.entryconfig("New", state="normal")
            listprob=[]
        root.after(1000,boucledef, boucle-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default parameter in python ... Once set, this arg has a memory space, so it wont need to call `random.randint(0,10)` the other times ...

Here's a workaround :

```
def boucledef(boucle=None):
    global copienom, listprob
    if boucle == None :
        boucle = random.randint(0,10)
    if boucle>0:
    ...
```

For more information, python default argument are evaluated when the function is created, not when you call it. If you want to have a closer look, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) can help you.